# backbone trigger event loses context with two cases

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

We have a parent View, and multiple children Views, one type of `primary` and another `secondary`.  We are transitioning both the parent and children views at the same time, and to do so, we have a `'transition.event'` that we trigger in the parent via `dispatch.trigger('transition.event', this)` and a listener on the child views via

```
initialize: function(options) {
  if(options) {
    ... we place everything from options.* onto this.*
    // we can verify that the parameters exist coming in from options
    // This is listener A
    dispatch.on('transition.event', this.transition, this);
  }
  ...
  // This is listener B
  dispatch.on('transition.event', this.transition, this);
  this.render();
}
```

The options case is for when the type is set to `secondary`.

If we remove listener A, the event DOES NOT work because context is lost.
If we remove listener B, the event DOES WORK, and context is of course not lost.
If we change listener A to `dispatch.on('secondaryTransition.event, this.transition, this);` and leave listener B as is, it works.

Why do we lose context and some parameters when setting conditional listeners to backbone triggers?

More complete code:

Parent View:

```
makeChildViews: function(options){
  this.measurePassingToChildViewParameters = {...};
  // for each child 
  _.all(this.parentMeasureModel.get('beats').models, function(beat, index) {
    // create a Childview
      ...
        this.lineStatesUnrolling = [...];
        this.lineStatesRollup = [...];

    this.measurePassingToChildViewParameters.lineStatesUnrolling = this.lineStatesUnrolling;
    this.measurePassingToChildViewParameters.lineStatesRollup = this.lineStatesRollup;
    // we can verify that the parameters exist when we create the Child view
    new ChildView(this.measurePassingToChildViewParameters);
  }, this);
},
```

Child View:

```
transition: function() {
  // even though the parameters came in from the (options) in the init
  // they disappear when we have both listeners set
  console.warn(this);  //here this.lineStatesUnrolling is undefined
  for(i=0; i<this.transitionNumberOfPoints; i++){
      var x = this.transitionNumberOfPoints-i;
      this.BEAT.data([this.lineStatesUnrolling[i]])
          .transition()
          .delay(this.transitionDuration*i)
          .duration(this.transitionDuration)
          .ease('linear')
          .attr('d', this.pathFunction)
  }
},
```

Error: Can not access [0] of undefined

Comment: is your dispatch acting as a custom event bus?

Comment: @beNerd  Yes, I inherited that idea.  `dispatch` handles events between multiple views   Not sure if there is a conventional way of handling that in BB...